# VisualForce page to allow inline editing of EmailTemplate HTML

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, html, inputtext

Thanks for taking a look at my problem.

I am building a VisualForce page to email all CampaignMembers associated with a Campaign record. Everything is working except for one little thing:

I have an  tag that is rendered when the user clicks "Edit Template". The idea is that the user can preview the email that is going to be sent, which I do by displaying the EmailTemplate.HtmlValue with .

Here's my relevant code:

```
<!--VisualForce Page -->
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!editMode}">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Edit Template" />
    <apex:inputTextarea id="editTemplate" value="{!strMessage}" richText="true" cols="100" rows="15"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

/* Controller */
editedTemplate.HtmlValue = strMessage;
update editedTemplate;
```

So the problem I am getting, when using the rich-text editor, is the following exception:

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The HTML Email Content contains improperly
>   formatted merge fields. Please check the format of all the merge
>   fields to ensure they start with {! and end with }.: [HtmlValue]

Although I can get it to work with the plain-text editor. However, it is displayed like this:

```
<table height="400" width="550" cellpadding="5" border="0" cellspacing="5" >
<tr height="400" valign="top" >
<td style=" color:#000000; font-size:12pt; background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; bLabel:main; bEditID:r3st1;" tEditID="c1r1" locked="0" aEditID="c1r1" >
<![CDATA[<font face="arial"><font size="3">Dear&nbsp;</font>{!Contact.Salutation}&nbsp;{!Contact.LastName},</font><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><br></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;">How are you today? I enjoyed our meeting, let's meet again soon!</div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><br></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;">Sincerely,</div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><br></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial"><b>{!User.Name}</b></font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial">{!User.CompanyName}</font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial">{!User.Phone}</font></div><div><font face="arial">{!User.Email}</font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial"><br></font></div>]]></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Unformatted HTML is not appropriate for displaying to the end-user.

Any ideas why the rich-text editor would cause the exception above? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You might find the answer [Here](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Problem-creating-HTML-Email-Template-3774731.S.160526607)

Comment: Are you working with a letterhead template?

Comment: And are you trying to do any DML statements on the EmailTemplate (insert/update/upsert) or is your goal just displaying a formatted version of the template

Comment: The goal is to immediately send out an email with the edited version of the template - so what I'm doing is creating a new EmailTemplate, copying the field values from the one that is being edited, and then inserting it as a new EmailTemplate after it has been edited. Then, after the email is sent, I delete the new template, as it is only needed for the single email blast. The only way I know to use it is to insert it since I need it for mail.setTemplateId(ID templateId)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to complete your code to achieve what you describe and found a little problem: sending the email will create a Task object, which conflicts with saving an EmailTemplate (you get a MIXED_DML_OPERATION).

What I ended up doing is creating separate buttons for the save and the email. I used a TemporalTemplate to store the modified version so I can reuse it.

You may be able to avoid the MIXED_DML_OPERATION by using a @Future method to send the email after the save.

Here's my code:

```
<apex:page controller="EmailTemplateController">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!sendMail}" value="Send Email"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveTemplate}" value="Save Template"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Target Contact" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!targetContact.ReportsToId}"/>    
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Edit Template" />
    <apex:inputTextarea id="editTemplate" value="{!editedTemplate}" richText="true" cols="100" rows="15"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the controller:

```
public with sharing class EmailTemplateController {
    public Contact targetContact {get;set;}
    public String editedTemplate {get;set;}
    private String templateId = null;
    public EmailTemplateController() {
        targetContact = new Contact();
        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('template')) {
            templateId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('template');
            this.editedTemplate = [select HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where Id = :templateId].HtmlValue;
        }
    }

    public PageReference saveTemplate() {
        EmailTemplate template =  [select Id, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where Name = 'TemporalTemplate'];
        template.HtmlValue = editedTemplate;
        update template;

        return null;
    }

    public PageReference sendMail() {
        EmailTemplate template =  [select Id, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where Name = 'TemporalTemplate'];

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setSenderDisplayName('Tester');
        email.setTemplateId(template.Id);
        email.setTargetObjectId(targetContact.ReportsToId);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been tinkering around with email templates alot lately and had a similar problem that might explain why this is failing, and will probably not work. I tried to store a rendered email in a custom field in salesforce, and since I had HTML I thought, why not store it in a richtext field, that way I should be able to see the rendered html instead of the code.

But what I found was that the richtext editor strips quite some mark-up form your templates when trying to load the html in there, I think the default rich text editor you get in salesforce (and probably 3rd pary components aswel) aren't suited for email template editing. 
As email templates normally have a different mark-up than websites, and most editors (if not all) are used for trying to provide a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) experience for editing websites (and still the html that is generated from those, is mostly utter garbage), I think it'll be hard to find an editor that will work for you. Next to that, bad formatted or *ugly* html will result in a lower deliverability as spam filters pick that up.

If you look at mass emailing solutions in the likes of MailChimp, VerticalResponse, iContact, ... none seem to provide a **real** WYSIWYG experience. I'm sure if you would find a solution for this there would be many interested parties. (Me included ;) make sure to contact me!)

I'm afraid you're stuck with using the salesforce template editor, or the salesforce "send an email" feature. And hope that salesforce is busy with some *killer* feature (as always: `Safe Harbor`)

Comment: You don't have any contact info on your profile, and SE doesn't allow PMs, so I can't contact you :) We're working on some new "email nerd" features in our native app that includes WYSIWYG, would love to have some early input on the next release if you're interested.

Comment: i'll send you a direct message on twitter (I got from your profile)